# Adjust height of image to 100% width without altering aspect ratio

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, aspect-ratio

I'm currently working on a project where we use a slider with images. This slider is displayed with width 100%, and currently we're adjusting the height to make the slider responsive, in case the user resizes the browser window or visits the website using their phone.

However, the website is for an artist who obviously does not want the image to be altered in any way, especially not altering with the aspect ratio. So what we're looking into is having `height: auto` to adjust the image height correctly according to the `width: 100%`, without altering the image (aspect ratio) itself.

This does not work like intended however, using the following code:

```
@media (min-width:1600px) {
    #header{
        height:auto;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 630px;
        background-size: 100% auto;
    }

    #slidershadow {
        height: 630px;
    }
}
```

We need to have some `min-height`, otherwise we cannot display the slider controls correctly. Here is a picture of our current situation (first image) and the expected behaviour (second picture).

[image: Adjust height of image to 100% width without altering aspect ratio]

Is there a way to resize our slider responsive, but keeping the following in mind:

- The aspect ratio of the image cannot be altered;
- We cannot crop images too much (only slightly);
- There is a minimum height to keep in mind;

If it helps, all images in the slider have the same size.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @dippas Yes I can, give me a second.

Comment: @dippas It looks something like the following: http://jsfiddle.net/2ofm1dv7/

Comment: Try to not use `min-height` and `height: auto;` together. In my mind, simply using `min-height` and `max-width` instead of `width` on the image should do the job, no?

Comment: @SimonDowdles I will try that, thanks. I'll keep you guys updated.

Comment: Let me know if this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/btsx6os0/, see full page result: http://jsfiddle.net/btsx6os0/embedded/result/

Comment: Want me to transform that in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give a `max-width:100%` to your `img`.

Plus `background-size` only works when you are working with `background-images`.

Since you are applying `max-width` to your `img` there is no need to apply `max-width` to its parent `#header`

Last, but not least try not use `min-height` and `height:auto` at same time in the same selector.

Below is a working snippet according to the above comments:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto
}
@media (min-width: 1280px) {
  #header {
    min-height: 500px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  #header {
    min-height: 630px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x630" />
</div>
```